# What's the counter for episodes?

Tags: words, counters

How can I say "I watched 13 episodes so far" in Japanese? What is the counter for episodes?

I also would like to know the right word for episode. Is it 挿話? That's what I found on jisho.org but since there are no example sentences I have no way of knowing whether this is really the right word.

If possible please could you add the word for season? (see my comment to the answer)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For your purpose, the most often-used word would be 「話{わ}」 followed probably by 「回{かい}」, but ***not*** 「挿話{そうわ}」.

「挿話」 is more like an "anecdote" or a little "side-story".

Ordinally, we say 「第{だい}(number)話{わ}」 or 「第{だい}(number)回{かい}」 .

Cardinally, we say 「(number)話」,「(number)話分{わぶん}」,「(number)回分{かいぶん}」, etc.

> "I watched 13 episodes so far." =

「第13話まで観{み}た。」(You watched episodes #1 thru #13.)

「13話分(を)観た。」(You watched a combined total of 13 random episodes.)

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm so glad I asked. If I had used 挿話 this would have ended up in another embarrassing situation where I say something no one understands. > . <

Comment: I know you ignore comments but I have to try anyway (otherwise I have to make a new question just for one word): What is the word for "season"? Do you mind adding it to your answer? Like e.g. I want to say "I watched 13 episodes of season 1 so far."

Comment: @ナウシカ You can always ask that as a separate question :-)

Comment: @ナウシカ I already have four candidates in mind, and this space is too small :-)

Comment: \\(^o^)/ Thank you snailboat and naruto! Ok, I will make a new question.