# The word for "season" (US) or "series" (UK)?

Tags: words, english-to-japanese

I previously [asked how to count episodes](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/25919/whats-the-counter-for-episodes) but I forgot to ask how to say "series". How can I say

> I watched 13 episodes of season 1.

Answer (score 10):

You can use **期【き】, シリーズ, 部【ぶ】, or シーズン**, all of which are common. Here are the examples taken from Wikipedia (I haven't confirmed, but presumably these reflect the official namings):

> - [けいおん!　第2期](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%91%E3%81%84%E3%81%8A%E3%82%93!)
> - [3年B組金八先生　第7シリーズ（2004年 - 2005年）](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/3%E5%B9%B4B%E7%B5%84%E9%87%91%E5%85%AB%E5%85%88%E7%94%9F)
> - [Xファイル　第5シーズン (*or* シーズン5)](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/X%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB)
> - [水戸黄門　第38部 (2008年)](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B0%B4%E6%88%B8%E9%BB%84%E9%96%80_(%E3%83%91%E3%83%8A%E3%82%BD%E3%83%8B%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF_%E3%83%89%E3%83%A9%E3%83%9E%E3%82%B7%E3%82%A2%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC))

These are basically interchangeable, but here's my impression:

- 期: very common
- シリーズ: next common
- 部: orthodox, serious
- シーズン: [technical/formal](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B7%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BA%E3%83%B3_(%E3%83%86%E3%83%AC%E3%83%93)), relatively a bit uncommon, fits well with foreign dramas

You can use these words to count the number of seasons, too, by just removing 第:

> - 「けいおん!」は**2期**に分けて製作された。
> - 「3年B組金八先生」は32年間、**8シリーズ**にわたって放映された。

And we have another unit to count TV series, [クール](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB_(%E6%94%BE%E9%80%81)), which roughly corresponds to 12-13 weeks (episodes), starting from April (春クール, and so forth), July, October and January. It's either from German *Kur* or French *cours*, according to Wikipedia. Virtually all Japanese TV dramas and anime are produced under this クール system, and in many cases 1クール exactly corresponds to 1期/シリーズ.

It's unlikely that broadcasting companies officially use クール (it used to be jargon only used by professionals). But now it's widely used among anime/drama fans. For example, you can say:

> - 「けいおん!」は2期に分けて、合計3クール製作された。(Indicates there are approx. 36-39 episodes. cf. [List of K-On! episodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_K-On!_episodes))
> - 第2クール
> - [分割2クール](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E5%88%86%E5%89%B22%E3%82%AF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB) (24-26 episodes in total, but with a certain interval after broadcasting the first 12-13 episodes)

Comment: I only saw シーズン used w/ foreign (basically US) shows.

Comment: Some very popular 日本のドラマ such as [古畑任三郎](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8F%A4%E7%95%91%E4%BB%BB%E4%B8%89%E9%83%8E) and [相棒](http://www.tv-asahi.co.jp/aibou/) use シーズン.

Comment: Wow, thank you. I'm surprised that there are 4 different words!

Comment: Fair enough.  For what it's worth I dodged Japanese TV like the plague for ages. ;)

Comment: I think 期/シーズン and シリーズ have different connotations. シリーズ sounds to me more like "franchise" where they put same core characters into different places, settings or plots etc. rather than ordinary sequels.