# 数え方（ドラマのエピソードの場合）

Tags: word-requests, counters

英語の場合はepisode 1, episode 2...という数え方がありますが、日本語の場合はどういった数え方で数えるでしょうか？

Comment: あっ！同じ質問がすでにありました　https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/25925/9831

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「[第一話]{だいいちわ}、[第二話]{だいにわ}...」と数えることが多いと思います。